# Why does a system call table exist and not just appended to the interrupt vector table?

Tags: interrupt

Why does a system call table exist and not just appended to the interrupt vector table? I don't understand the design choice here. If it improves performance to differentiate events, why not system calls then?

Comment: I would guess because they are both indexed tables, and liable to grow over time, so why have to adjust offsets every time something changes? Also, system calls arise from user processes, and interrupts from hardware, so they have different context switch requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven’t looked into the historical context behind the use of a single interrupt (0x80) for system calls on i386, there are a few reasons *not* to use separate software interrupts for individual system calls.

- The number of software interrupts is limited, which constrains the number of system calls (and on x86, a number of interrupt descriptor table entries need to be used for other purposes). There are now more systems calls than could be supported on most architectures using software interrupts.
- Quite a few architectures have dedicated system call instructions, which don’t use software interrupts (or equivalent thereof). This includes x86-64, [where the dedicated `SYSCALL` instruction provides faster system call access than software interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15168822/4500798). [`man 2 syscall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) provides details of each architecture’s system call conventions.

If you look at the details of the ARM/OABI architecture you might get the impression that an interrupt table was used there, since the system call number is encoded in the instruction; but [the corresponding instruction](https://heyrick.eu/aw/index.php?title=SWI) executes a fixed software interrupt, ignoring the encoded number, and the system call handler retrieves the number from the instruction itself. This approach was abandoned for EABI because it led to cache pollution (more recent ARM CPUs have separate instruction and data caches).

Answer (score 1):

For one, x86(-64) supports an [interrupt table of 256 entries](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table), some of which are used for actual hardware interrupts. Counting from the [man page `syscalls(2)` here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), there are over 400 different system calls on Linux. Probably not all exist on all architectures, but also, according to [another list](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/), there are 314 different system calls on x86-64 (0 to 313). So, at least for Linux on x86, there seems to be no way to reserve a distinct interrupt number for each system call.

Of course, x86 isn't the only architecture there is. It's possible that others have even less software interrupts available, or have a completely distinct path for system calls, separate from hardware interrupts. In fact, modern x86(-64), already has such a separate path, by way of [the SYSCALL and SYSENTER instructions](https://wiki.osdev.org/SYSCALL):

> The SYSENTER/SYSEXIT instructions (and equivalent SYSCALL/SYSRET on AMD) enable fast entry to the kernel, avoiding interrupt overhead.

Another possible reason to use only a single entry point to the kernel would be any mandatory arrangements related to the userspace/kernel switch, independent of the particular system call. Perhaps some state needs to be saved, or the stack switched. Any such would again depend on the particular features of the architecture and the system design, but if there are such tasks to do, it may be easier to do them in just one place. (Especially because such low level tasks may need to be the very first thing to do, before being even able to do function calls in the new context.)

---

Note that most of the above is pretty much just conjecture, I'm not at all familiar with any non-x86 architectures (apart from maybe some that don't run general-purpose OS's) and haven't looked at the Linux system call implementation that closely, let alone those of other operating systems. If you need more low-level details, I hope someone else will be able to provide them.